# Detect single-character xor (OCaml)

Tags: type-safety, ocaml

I have been working through the [Cryptopals](https://cryptopals.com) challenges in Ocaml. My interest in Ocaml is to better learn functional programming techniques and effective usage of the type system.

[Set 1 Challenge 4](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/4) says 'One of the 60-character strings in this file has been encrypted by single-character XOR. Find it.'

My code finds the correct string. I tried using user-defined types (e.g. `xor_input`, `xor_output`) to avoid passing around lots of `string` types that could easily be muddled. However, I am not sure of what is an appropriate level of type annotation. For example:

- is there any merit in `make_ranking` specifying a return type of `score` if it ends in `|> Score`? My understanding of Haskell is that I could use the function's type annotation to specify that it returns a `Score` and the `int` returned from the `fold` would automatically be wrapped in a `score` type - is there something similar in Ocaml? `|> Score` seems a cumbersome way to specify the return type.
- I was also unsure how to convert to and from a user-defined type and its unwrapped value (e.g. `score` and `int`). My approach in `sort_results` and `output` (destructuring) seems inelegant to me.
- in `sort_results` I destructure the arguments to get the scores. Does this not mean that any type with a `score` field will be accepted?

(Note that `Hexx` is a module I wrote to convert a base64 encoded string to a hex string. Assume the input is a file containing a list of strings.)

```
open Core

let english = "etaoin srhldcumfpgwybvkxjqzETAOINSRHLDCUMFPGWYBVKXJQZ0123456789.?!"

type score = Score of int
type xor_input = Xor_input of string
type xor_output = Xor_output of string
type result =
  {
    test_char : char;
    score : score;
    xor_input : xor_input;
    xor_output : xor_output;
  }

let xor c (Xor_input input) : xor_output =
  String.map input ~f:(fun l -> int_of_char l |> (lxor) c |> char_of_int) |> Xor_output

let make_ranking (Xor_output str) : score =
  String.fold str ~init:0 ~f:(fun total c ->
      total + match String.index english c with
              | Some v -> v
              | None -> 100 (* arbitary value for non-letters *)
    ) |> Score

let make_result (input : xor_input) c : result =
  let output = xor c input in
  { test_char = char_of_int c; score = make_ranking output; xor_input = input; xor_output = output }

let sort_results { score = first; _ } { score = second; _ } =
  let (Score first_val) = first in
  let (Score second_val) = second in
  first_val - second_val

let find_best_match results : result =
  let best = List.sort ~cmp:sort_results results |> List.hd in
  match best with
  | Some x -> x
  | None -> failwith "No best result found"

let xor_line line =
  let decoded = Hexx.decode line in
  List.range 0 255
  |> List.map ~f:(make_result (Xor_input decoded))
  |> find_best_match

let output {test_char; score; xor_input; xor_output} =
  let (Score s) = score in
  let (Xor_input input) = xor_input in
  let (Xor_output out) = xor_output in
  fprintf stdout "Char: %c, Score: %d, Original: %s, Output: %s\n" test_char s input out

let () =
  In_channel.read_lines "4.txt"
  |> List.map ~f:xor_line
  |> find_best_match
  |> output
```

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on tackling cryptopals! These are great exercises and very interesting to learn new languages and techniques.

### Syntax

#### Remove the type annotations

In most cases in OCaml, you don't need any type annotations. So instead of:

```
let make_result (input : xor_input) c : result =
```

It's more usual to write:

```
let make_result input c =
```

The reason is that for exposed functions, the type will be in the `.mli` file, and for local functions, it's only one key binding away in your editor thanks to [merlin](https://github.com/ocaml/merlin).

#### Pipelines

The pipe operator is powerful and works well in some cases like your main function, but combined with partial application and infix operators, it can become hard to read.

I'd rewrite:

```
fun l -> int_of_char l |> (lxor) c |> char_of_int
```

As:

```
fun l -> char_of_int (c lxor (int_of_char l))
```

#### Pattern tricks

In places like this:

```
let (Xor_input input) =
```

You can omit the parens and just write:

```
let Xor_input input =
```

You can also perform several layers of pattern matching in one step. So rather than writing

```
let sort_results { score = first; _ } { score = second; _ } =
  let (Score first_val) = first in
  let (Score second_val) = second in
```

You can write:

```
let sort_results { score = Score first_val; _ } { score = Score second_val; _ } =
```

#### Record shorthand syntax

When building a record, parts that look like `label = label` can be written just `label`. So you can rename variables and change:

```
let make_result input c =
  let output = xor c input in
  { test_char = char_of_int c; score = make_ranking output; xor_input = input; xor_output = output }
```

To:

```
let make_result xor_input c =
  let xor_output = xor c xor_input in
  { test_char = char_of_int c; score = make_ranking output; xor_input; xor_output }
```

### Type design

I don't think that the `xor_input` and `xor_output` bring a lot here. You're probably be as OK with plain strings.

### Other remarks

You are sorting a whole list just to get the minimal element. There is probably a function to do that in `core` (and it will be linear).

Instead of `fprintf stdout`, you can just use `printf`.

That's it! Have a nice journey learning OCaml and please post other examples on this site :)